# Do I need Webpack for Typescript with Visual Studio 2017 or not?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, typescript

I'm a bit confused on this topic, and it's not clear to me from the documentation at www.typscriptlang.org . Do I need something like webpack, gulp, etc. to get the transpiled javascript with Visual Studio 2017, or can I just use the typescript config file without any additional help.  I tried running my sample project, but I got uncaught reference errors for the keyword export not being defined in my javascript.  I'm just looking for a simple explanation on the matter.

Comment: You don't especially need webpack or gulp or any kind of other tool. But you do need the [typescript compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links)

Comment: It's installed and I get the built javascript files from my ts files, but I get reference errors in the browser.